# How do I remove a single object in a cell of a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using UICollectionView and with this method i can delete all objects that I have added to CoreData:

```
- (IBAction)btnDelete:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" message:@"Delete all favorites?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 0){
        nil;
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1){
        AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *execQuery =[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *descOggetto = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"HexCode" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [execQuery setEntity:descOggetto];
        NSError *error = nil;
        _arr = [context executeFetchRequest:execQuery error:&error];

        for (NSManagedObject *ogg in _arr){
            [context deleteObject:ogg];
            [_favoriteCollectionView reloadData];
        }

        NSError *saveError = nil;
        [context save:&saveError];

        // NSLog(@"Delete");
    }
}
```

How do I delete a single object instead of all?

Comment: Depends. Which object do you want to delete?

Comment: If you use this command: [context DeleteObject: ogg] deletes all objects in CoreData, instead I want to delete only the object contained in the cell.

Comment: No. In the code you posted, you're fetching all objects, iterating over them, and deleting them one at a time. The command  `[context deleteObject:ogg]` only deletes one object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown enough code for me to give you a specific answer. But the general outline is like this:

First you need to get the index path of the cell associated with the managed object you want to delete. How you do that depends on your use case:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = ...;
```

From there, get the managed object from your data model. If your data model is a mutable array (typical when you only have one section in your collection view):

```
NSManagedObject *obj = [self.myDataModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
```

Then you delete the object and remove it from the array:

```
[obj.managedObjectContext deleteObject:obj];
NSError *saveError = nil
[obj.managedObjectContext save:saveError];
...// error handling
[self.myDataModel removeObject:obj];
```

Finally, you inform the collection view that you've deleted an item so it can update the display:

```
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
```

Or if you don't want animation:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

The answer is a little bit different if you're using an `NSFetchedResultsController`. Some of the above steps would be taken care of in your `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` implementation as outlined in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). The remaining steps would look something like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = ...;
NSManagedObject *obj = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[obj.managedObjectContext deleteObject:obj];
NSError *saveError = nil
[obj.managedObjectContext save:saveError];
...// error handling
```

Comment: What do you mean when you write: self.myDataModel?

Comment: It's a hypothetical property that references your data model. The point of that line is to illustrate that you need to retrieve the object for the given index path from your data model.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I solved it by following your advice.